# Error when accesing .ashx file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx, ihttphandler

Goal:
Created **client.ashx** by copying existing and working **product.ashx** and renaming into **client.ashx**
Modified **client.ashx** to handle similar logic to **product.ashx**

I did the above since I don't know how to create an .ashx from scratch  in visual studio community. I didn't see a file option for .ashx after the Add/New Item ...

The goal is to upload client images using **client.ashx**.
File **product.ashx** uploads product images.

My jscript call to product.ashx works as usual, although when I call the new client.ashx it seems to call product.ashx rather than  client.ashx

Sample call to client.ashx

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/handlers/client.ashx",
        data: formData,
        global: false,
        success: function (result) {

            var response = JSON.parse(result);
            var success = response.Success;

            if (success) {
                window.location.replace(window.location);
            }
            else {
                ChangeStatusMessage(response.Message, false, true);
            }
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function (result) {
            ChangeStatusMessage("An unknown error occurred while trying to upload the image.  Please reload the page and try again", false, true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's a common mistake. You probably forgot to change the code behind reference in the new file (it's probably pointing to the old .cs file)

Comment: BTW: Visual Studio does have a new .ashx file template, it's called 'Generic Handler' in 'New', 'File'.

Comment: if you just call it alone its run ? (alone in url)

Comment: in visual studio you create this file under asp.net handler

Comment: No, Code behind is the is the same file name.

Comment: Thanks Poul Bak. I just found it. I'm going to try creating the file from scratch.